# How do I go about determining whether a relation is reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been given these relations and I've been told to determine whether they're reflexive and I know the definition of reflexive but I don't really understand it.

$R=\{(x,y)\ \in\ \mathbb Z^2\ |\ x^2+y^2\ \text{is odd}\}$

$R=\{(x,y)\ \in\ \mathbb Q^2\ |\ xy \ge 0\}$

Comment: Go by the definition of reflexivity; put $(x, x)$ into the conditions for the relation and see if it holds.

Comment: The first relation is not reflexive, while the second it is. You have to check if $(x,x) \in R$.

Comment: @FrancescoChini How is the first relation reflexive?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to say the other way around..

Comment: reflexive means: every element is related to itself.  Examples of non reflexive numbers is aRb means a likes to eat b for dinner. (Nobody likes to eat themselves for dinner) or a + b an odd integer.  $2\not R 2$ as 2 + 2 is not an odd integer.  So 2 is not related to itself.  Or in set terms reflexive mean (x,x) $\in$ R which.... might very well not be true.  i) $x^2 + x^2 = 2x^2$ is not odd so $(x,x) \not \in R$.  not reflexive.  ii) $x*x = x^2 \ge 0$ so $(x,x) \in R$ so is reflexive.

Comment: I recommend that you edit the question and include the definition of "reflexive", word for word the way you received it (not in your own words). If what you say is true, that you really do not completely understand the definition, then to really understand the answers you need someone to clear up whatever lack of understanding you have of the definition. In order to clear up the definition for you, it is better to see it in the exact same form you saw it, to ensure that people don't start using notations or words that you've never seen.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a relation 
$$R=\{(x,y)\   | \mbox{ something something}\}$$

Checking reflexivity simply means: **If we set $x=y$ is "something something" always true (in the give set)?**

Thus for the first relation, you have to check if $x^2+x^2$ is always odd for $x$ integer.

For the second relation, you have to check if $xx \geq 0$ is always true for $x$ rational.

Answer (score 0):

A relation $R$ is said to be reflexive if $aRa$ for all $a$ in the domain.
So in
$$R=\{(x,y)\ \in \ \mathbb Z^2\ |\ x^2+y^2 is\:odd\}$$
$R$ will be reflexive if when $(a,a) \in \mathbb Z^2$ satisfies the relation for all $a \in \mathbb Z$. That is, if $2a^2$ is odd for all $a \in \mathbb Z$.

This is obviously false and thus the relation is not reflexive. Similarly, the other part can be solved.

Comment: So where did you get the expression $2a^2\  for\  all\  a\  \epsilon \  \mathbb \  Z$?

Comment: @GabrielleRebeccaForsey If $x=y=a$, $x^2+y^2=a^2+a^2=2a^2$

Comment: Thank you so much and why do we set x=y?

Comment: The definition of a reflexive relation is that $(a,a)$ is a member of the relation for all $a$ in the domain. You can call it by any name, say, $(x,x)$, for all $x$ in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

For the second relation: $$ R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q} | xy \geq 0 \} $$

if the relationship is reflexive then *x = y*. Therefore you can rewrite *xy* as $x^{2}$ or $y^{2} $. Now you just have to answer whether a squared rational will always be greater than or equal to zero.